# Bash script for notification when internet is accessible

Tags: bash, shell, terminal-emulator

I wrote this bash script to have a notification when internet becomes accessible but I don't understand many of things that are happening. Here is the script:

```
while ! ping 8.8.8.8 -c 1 2&> /dev/null ; do true; done;
```

- The `-c 1` option tells `ping` that i want to send only one packet.
- The `2&> /dev/null` is there because i don't want to see output.
- `true` is there because `bash` didn't accept the `do;` syntax.
- the terminating condition is `! ping ...` because `ping` returns non zero status code when no packet is received before some `timeout`.

The intended behavior was for this loop to end when `ping` succeeds and the terminal emulator will automatically send me a notification.

---

## Problems

- This command doesn't end even when internet becomes accessible.
- Trying to kill the command with `ctrl + C` doesn't work. I think it's killing the sub-command `ping` instead of the whole command.
- Only removing `2&> /dev/null` makes every thing works except for the minor issue that it writes output to the terminal.

---

## Questions

1. What's wrong with my command?
2. How exactly do terminal emulators react to `ctrl + C`?
3. Why does removing `2&> /dev/null` make it work?

Note that I already have a turnaround. Nevertheless I want to understand `bash` a little more.

```
f() { while ! ping 8.8.8.8 -c 1 ; do true; done; }; f 2&> /dev/null
```

Comment: my version of `ping` expects `ping -c 1 8.8.8.8` . Pluse-uno for exploring your problem! Good luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct redirection operator is `&>`, not `2&>`. The 2 is parsed as a separate argument to `ping`, and since pinging `2` never succeeds, the loop never exists.

Comment: * My fault. I failed to use this more verbose syntax `2>&1`.
* You don't explain the `Ctrl + C` problem. Is `Ctrl+C` killing the the ping command instead of the loop? because with your suggestion (`&>`), the command is ctrl-c-interrupt-able when there is no network (when ping is failing).

Comment: Ctrl+C sends an interrupt to the current foreground job, which might be `ping`, or it might be the shell, depending on when you actually type it.

Comment: This doesn't really explain what's happening. After fixing the redirection issue, the commands becomes ctrl-c-interupptible. If you take into account that most time will be spent waiting the ttl to expire. So the probability that my Ctrl + C catches the brief moment when shell is executing is null.

Comment: Never mind. After changing 8.8.8.8 to a non used address in my local network. IT BECAME IMPOSSIBLE TO INTERRUPT the command with Ctrl + C. The previous behavior I was experiencing (of the command being interruptible when there is no internet) was because `ping` was returning instantaneously because the network was unreachable. Now that the target address is potentially reachable, `ping` waits for a complete TTL. Therefore, It becomes impossible to catch the very brief moment of bash running.

Answer (score 3):

Something I usually do in that kind of loops is adding a `sleep` command instead of `true`:

```
while ! ping 8.8.8.8 -c 1 &> /dev/null ; do sleep 1; done;
```

In that way you can use `Ctrl+C` while in the sleep and cancel the whole loop.

Comment: Thanks but, apparently, `while ! ping 8.8.8.8 -c 1 &> /dev/null ; do true; done;` is interrupt-able, so I don't see a reason to use sleep. `true` is also shorter :p.

Comment: Yes, but it is less aggressive with your network :).

Comment: See my comment on @chepner response. I realize now the utility of the sleep function. It increases the likelihood that it's bash that is running when Ctrl + C is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

I think the better way is to setup Timeout in the ping.

```
while ! ping -c 1 -W 2 8.8.8.8 >/dev/null 2>&1 ; do sleep 1 ; done
```